A SF short story which is already partly true, no money transfer except by computers. And only ONE hacker has been able to steal
I read this short story about 40 years ago. I don't remember exactly, but probably in a collection since I read very few magazines. At that time, it was fully SF. Indeed, we still mostly paid with cash or checks. Electronic money transfer was just beginning.
In the story only electronic transfers, through "computers", were possible. But we are nearly there...
And in the story there was only just one hacker who had managed to steal money from the system. Here, the story is well behind our time...
The only remaining strong SF notion in the story was a technique to artificially cause an "allergy" to computers. The hacker was thus in a position where he was totally unable to buy anything, not even food, even though he had, like everyone else, a card with access to enough money. But he could not use it himself because of his allergy. He had to ask others to use it for him, which was an unsufferable humiliation, exposing him each time as the worst criminal of the time.

Definitely "A Perfect Fit"

@Andrew  You are right, it is "A perfect fit"

@beichst You are right in the sense that the answer is the same. But the answer there has not been accepted, so technically, I think that it is not considered as a dupe

Glad to hear this was the story you were seeking.  And you may be right.  It is technically not a dupe (which is why I had noted it as such). But the important part is we were able to get you connected with the story you were trying find.  :-)

Turns out we have had this one before. Established the proper dupe target.

@FuzzyBoots Oh, well....

As per Short story about cybercriminal sentenced not to use computers, this is "A Perfect Fit" by Isaac Asimov.

I have been adjusted, as you surely know, so that I am incapable of looking at a computer without hurting my eyes, or touching one without blistering my fingers. I can't even handle my cash card or even think of using it without nausea.

From the other answer:

The story was first published in EDN magazine in 1981 and is available on their website. It was collected in “The Winds of Change and Other Stories” in 1983.


So that we can get an accepted answer since the other one is not.

Totally off topic and completely gratuitous, but it sounds like the protagonist would fit in with everyone in Green Bank, West Virginia which has become a haven for people who are "electrosensitive".
